# Detect Shopware Version through API

Tags: api, shopware

Thank you in advance.

Is there any way to check Shopware version through API. for example shop URL - `https://example.shop.com` is a running Shopware 5 or Shopware 6 without using any credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, that is not possible, for both Shopware versions. This is totally intended, because disclosing its own version would be a high security breach.

If you want to differ between Shopware 5 and Shopware 6 you have to know which one you want to talk to via API beforehand, because the API routes are totally different.

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann

Comment: But, but the competitor can do that with `/magento_version` *SCNR*

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do for differentiating 5 and 6 is that you can use try-catch to send 2 kinds of api requests to the same API, one can be addressed to sw5 and one to sw6. One of the requests will return an error and one will not. In this way you will know the version of the Shopware.

Comment: Yes you are right, i tried this way to detect version Thank you @David

Answer (score 0):

For

- Shopware 6 you can check their API doc at the endpoint : http://domain/api/_info/swagger.html and for
- Shopware 5 you can find http://domain/api/version

By detecting this kind of endpoints you can find that it's the Shopware 5 or 6 without making the real API calls to receive the errors